# Different hash in PHP and C# using MD5 and Base64

Tags: c#, php, hash

I have problem with MD5 and Base64 functions in PHP and C#. When I try hash my string without polish chars it's ok but when I use polish chars returned different. How can I fix this?

**C#**

```
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tbPassword.Text)));
```

**PHP**

```
base64_encode(md5($string, true));
```

Comment: I don't know C# but I'd guess `Encoding.ASCII.` would cause an issue with polish characters.

Comment: It's not what's causing the problem, but why bother base64 encoding an MD5 hash?

Comment: Can you provide with a string that reproduces the issue?

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Yes, it's "łóżko2017"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through most likely a duplicate for this.

Comment: Does your C string come out look ok? Is it just the PHP that doesn't work here?

Comment: must I ask that again ^ ? or are you only responding to answers below instead? I'm trying to offer my help but you seem to have absented yourself or waiting for that "magic" solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using ASCII. Try Encoding.UTF8 instead or any other encoding that allows for extended characters. And another thing: Please don't use MD5 for passwords. It has been considered insecure for years.

Comment: I can't change C# code, I must do something in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the same encoding in PHP:

```
base64_encode(md5(mb_convert_encoding($string,"ASCII"), true));
```

Note that the obvious issues here (in both the C# and PHP code) is that you're losing information. The other obvious issue is that you're doing MD5 on what appears to be a password. That is a bad idea.

Here's a PHP example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e21dd185093817217427b6cd4e58a223e6ca3b27

Here's the C# example: http://csharppad.com/gist/b26f07cbf9d53d809490e931e6cfbe1d

Comment: This is not working. I have two different hashes. I know about it that MD5 this is bad idea but I am working on old project which have algorithms on this function.

Comment: It's working for the original input you supplied, what is it failing for?